# Joomla "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare jblogerror() in on line 0"

Tags: joomla, updates, fatal-error, redeclare

Here is a weird problem i'm facing; after updating Joomla to the latest version, website failed to up load but, as i've made a backup manually from these folders:
administrator
bin
cli
components
includes
layouts
libraries
modules
plugins
yt-assets
and all the root files, after restoring the backup still the website is not loading and just says
"Fatal error: Cannot redeclare jblogerror() in on line 0" !

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the version of jBlog you are using is loading its attempting to load its own classes twice.

Let's assume the jBlog developers already fixed it and you carelessly ignored the warning to ensure all your extensions are compatible before updating.

Are you able to access administrator? Simply go there and upgrade jBlog including any modules.

Else, the issue lies within a plugin. In order to access the administrator and perform the update, you will need to manually disable the offending plugin.

A simple way is to rename its folder: start from plugins/system then plugins/content hopefully you'll have spotted it by then. Look into the subfolders of each and spot any that may be relevant to jBlog (or grep through the folder to locate the specific string)

If you have console access, simply run

```
# grep -rl jblogerror plugins/system
```

and you should see all the files that include such string, just rename their main plugin folder.  But you could also do all this through ftp and guessing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't have console access just cpanel, the interesting thing is that i've made a full public_html backup before doing anything wrong and when it was working fine, after upgrading a plugin i guess this error appeared. but now even if i clear the public folder and extract the backed up file it still gives me that error! isn't it weird?

Comment: It could be due to inconsistencies in the database (if you restore the backup of the db as well it could work) or be totally unrelated. An update usually adds columns to the database, and does not remove them, so it's unusual; but since it's ultimately up to the developer, and lacking better cues, it's worth mentioning.